# How to find out all the different blocktyp pesent in a Simulink model?

Tags: matlab, simulink

is there a way to find out all the block type involve in a Model, i guess it should be able with get_parameter ?
thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with `find_system` to get all blocks.
Get the `BlockType` for each and finally apply `unique` to get each type only once in the result.

```
%get the path to all blocks
all_blocks=find_system('untitled','lookundermasks','all','type','block')
%get the block type
unique(get_param(all_blocks,'BlockType'))
```

For the `lookundermasks` option, make sure to chose the option you want.